# How to use infrared sensor in Android-studio?

Tags: android, android-sensors, infrared

I have Xiaomi MI smartphone and it has infrared sensor. I am interested, how can I get access to sensor's class and which methods it's class has. I tried to find the information on other resources, but with no results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use

> SensorManager

. There is a method called

> getSensorList(int type)

that you can use to check all the sensors a certain device has. For example you can do similar to the following

```
  SensorManager mSensorManager = (SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
  Sensor mAccelerometer = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
```

See [this for a detailed description of Sensors](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager).